# How to run a 12V device with a 5V supply?

Tags: power-supply, power, dc-dc-converter

I have a fairly low-power 12 V device which I'd like to power from a 5 V Li-po power pack.

Assuming my 5 V source has enough total power, is there a simple converter I can connect between the device and the 5 V power pack to convert the voltage as needed? What would be a quick example I could take a look at to get started?

Comment: Look at your distributor for a "dc-dc boost converter 5v to 12v" and you'll find many.

Comment: Yes there is, do you want to design it yourself or are you asking what to buy?